# Cassandra counter readtimeout error

Tags: cassandra, timeout, counter, cql, cassandra-3.0

I have a storm topology that inserts data into a Cassandra counter table. This table has 6 partition keys, 4 primary keys and 5 counters.

When data starts to be inserted, I can query the counters correctly but after a few minutes updating the table with thousands of events, I get a readtimeout everytime I try to read one of the rows from the table (the most frequently updated). Other rows I can read quick and fine. Also if I run "select *", the top few hundreds are returned quick and fine as expected.

I am using Cassandra 3.6

The exact error:

```
ReadTimeout: Error from server: code=1200 [Coordinator node timed out waiting for replica nodes' responses] message="Operation timed out - received only 0 responses." info={'received_responses': 0, 'required_responses': 1, 'consistency': 'ONE'}
```

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table(
    pk1 bigint,
    pk2 tinyint,
    pk3 int,
    pk4 int,
    pk5 int,
    pk6 int,

    ck1 bigint,
    ck2 boolean,
    ck3 boolean,
    ck4 bigint,

    c1 counter,
    c2 counter,
    c3 counter,
    c4 counter,
    c5 counter,

    PRIMARY KEY ((pk1, pk2, pk3, pk4, pk5, pk6), ck1, ck2, ck3, ck4)
);
```

Query that fails:

```
select c1
from my_table
where pk1=-1and pk2=0 and pk3=0 and pk4=0
and pk5=0 and pk6=0 and ck1=1518739200000 and ck3=true and ck4=false and ck2=0;
```

Query that works:

```
select c1
from my_table
where pk1=720576073523265855 and pk2=0 and pk3=0 and pk4=0
and pk5=0 and pk6=0 and ck1=1518739200000 and ck3=true and ck4=false and ck2=1152930028237901798;
```

Other query that works:

```
select *
from my_table
limit 500;
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that one of your nodes in dead, but you have live nodes. Thus, the queries that query data from the dead nodes fail, but the rest of the queries succeed.

You can check the status of your cluster with the following command:

```
nodetool status
```

You can also check which node contains the actual data for a specific partition key with the command

```
nodetool getendpoints my_keyspace my_table pk1:pk2:pk3:pk4:pk5:pk6
```

(my_keyspace, my_table and pk1..pk6 stand for actual values)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help.

I have updated the cluster to Cassandra 3.11.1 and the counter table is finally working correctly.

I can only assume that I was a problem with version 3.6